# Performance of many checkboxes with .prop and .html

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, function, prop

I have many checkboxes, and i print with .Prop Jquery when this are checked, and his respective date with .html, who is the best manner to do fast or my method is the most fast?.

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:pathJS+'/php/requisitos/documents.php',
        async:false,
        dataType:'json'
    }).done(function(docs){

       if(docs.actaJSON == 1){
            $('#actCheck').prop('checked',true);
            $('#actF').html(docs.factaJSON);
        }

        if(docs.curpJSON == 1){
            $('#curpCheck').prop('checked',true);
            $('#curpf').html(docs.fcurpJSON);
        }

        if(docs.fotiJSON == 1){
            $('#ftCheck').prop('checked',true);
            $('#fotF').html(docs.ffotiJSON);
        }

        if(docs.fotTJSON == 1){
            $('#ftiCheck').prop('checked',true);
            $('#fotiF').html(docs.ffotTJSON);
        }
       //.......etc.
```

Comment: set up an array that maps your `docs` keys to the dom IDs, then have a loop. `mapping = {"actaJSON":['actCheck','actF], "curpJSON":['curpCheck',curpf'], etc...}`, and then a simple `$.each(mapping, ....)`

Comment: FYI, `async:false,` is deprecated and anyway should never be used. Now regarding your question, use common class for all checkboxes and any transversal method for relevant `date`

Comment: how many checkboxes are them? how do you know that this is the first point to attack to gain performance?

Comment: Performance isn't nearly as much of an issue here as having to duplicate similar code blocks that can be reduced down  to mapping array and a loop. When you start duplicating blocks like this numerous times there is almost always  a way to streamline it